# Ansible doesn't pick up group_vars without loading it manually

Tags: ansible

In my `local.yml` I'm able to run the playbook and reference variables within `group_vars/all` however I'm not able to access variables within `group_vars/phl-stage`. Let's assume the following.

```
ansible-playbook -i phl-stage site.yml
```

I have a variable, let's call it *`deploy_path`* that's different for each environment. I place the variable within `group_vars/< environment name >`. If I include the file `group_vars/phl-stage` within `vars_files` it works but I would've thought the group file would be automatically loaded?

site.yml

```
- include: local.yml
```

local.yml

```
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local

  vars_files:
    - "group_vars/perlservers"
    - "group_vars/deploy_list"
```

group_vars/phl-stage

```
[webservers]
phl-web1
phl-web2

[perlservers]
phl-perl1
phl-perl2

[phl-stage:children]
webservers
perlservers
```

Directory structure:

```
group_vars
  all
  phl-stage
  phl-prod
site.yml
local.yml
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You're confusing the structure a bit.

- The `group_vars` directory contains files *for each hostgroup* defined in your inventory file. The files define variables that member hosts can use.
- The inventory file doesn't reside in the `group_vars` dir, it should be outside.
- **Only** hosts that are members of a group can use its variables, so unless you put 127.0.0.1 in a group, it won't be able to use any group_vars beside those defined in `group_vars/all`.

What you want is this dir structure:

```
group_vars/
   all
   perlservers
   phl-stage
hosts
site.yml
local.yml
```

Your hosts file should look like this, assuming 127.0.0.1 is just a staging server and not perl or web server:

```
[webservers]
phl-web1
phl-web2

[perlservers]
phl-perl1
phl-perl2

[phl-stage]
127.0.0.1

[phl-stage:children]
webservers
perlservers
```

So you define which hosts belong to which group in the inventory, and then for each group you define variables in its group_vars file.

Comment: Thank you for this. I am dazzled that Ansible documentation pages mentioned nothing about this.

Comment: May be new in the Docs, but thought it would be helpful to provide a link https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables.